# The command has not been executed - Republicated With New Informations - MATCH Clause

Tags: orientdb

I have a Orientdb Database with 2 vertex

Pesquisador with 1 million records

Publicacao with 1 million records too

and an Edge COLABORA_COM with 6,239,382

I need select thousand researchers with the highest number of publications.

I execute the command

```
    SELECT  psq1.psq_nome AS nomePesquisador, COUNT(pub1) AS qtdPub
    FROM (
      MATCH 
        {class:Pesquisador, as:psq1}.outE("PUBLICOU").inV(){as:pub1}
      RETURN psq1, pub1
    )
    GROUP BY psq1
    ORDER BY qtdPub DESC, nomePesquisador
    LIMIT 1000;
```

then there are the error "The command has not been executed"

But if a execute the query

```
    SELECT ordem, out.psq_nome, out.psq_data_nascimento
    FROM PUBLICOU 
    WHERE in.pub_id = 5022
    ORDER BY ordem;
```

the query execute ok

is there an error of memory with MATCH?

Should I change the memory settings?

Comment: Could you post the server log ?

Comment: How many vertices of publicou do you get from "SELECT ordem, out.psq_nome, out.psq_data_nascimento
    FROM PUBLICOU 
    WHERE in.pub_id = 5022
    ORDER BY ordem;"

Comment: Sorry Alessandro I posted the second query wrong. the correct second query is         SELECT out.psq_nome AS nomePesquisador,     COUNT(in.@rid) AS qtdPub
FROM Publicou
GROUP BY out.psq_nome
ORDER BY qtdPub DESC, nomePesquisador
LIMIT 1000;

Comment: Could you post the server log ?

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:02:476 INFO  Loading configuration from: C:/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2016-08-02 08:27:03:360 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.2.5 (build 2.2.x@rf5282664db9300ef3358fb4d7e2066ad418c2e61; 2016-07-08 12:30:59+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2016-08-02 08:27:03:406 INFO  Databases directory: C:\orientdb\databases [OServer]
2016-08-02 08:27:05:514 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.36, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:05:519 INFO  Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2016-08-02 08:27:05:578 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'studio-2.2.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]
2016-08-02 08:27:05:705 INFO  Installed GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
2016-08-02 08:27:05:707 INFO  [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Error on resolving property: distributed [orientechnologies]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:05:743 WARNI Authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
2016-08-02 08:27:05:749 INFO  ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator is active [ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator]
2016-08-02 08:27:05:752 INFO  OServerConfigAuthenticator is active [OServerConfigAuthenticator]
2016-08-02 08:27:05:755 INFO  OSystemUserAuthenticator is active [OSystemUserAuthenticator]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:05:759 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v2.2.5 (build 2.2.x@rf5282664db9300ef3358fb4d7e2066ad418c2e61; 2016-07-08 12:30:59+0000). [OServer]
2016-08-02 08:27:21:855 WARNI {db=OSystem} Storage 'OSystem' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:21:858 INFO  {db=OSystem} Looking for last checkpoint... [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:22:198 INFO  {db=OSystem} Found FUZZY checkpoint. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:22:198 INFO  {db=OSystem} Found FUZZY checkpoint. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:22:207 INFO  {db=OSystem} Data restore procedure from FUZZY checkpoint is started. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:22:212 WARNI {db=OSystem} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=423247}} will be skipped during data restore [OLocalPaginatedStorage]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:22:215 WARNI {db=OSystem} Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=423254}} com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null, previousCheckpoint=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=423207}} will be skipped during data restore [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:22:217 WARNI {db=OSystem} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=423294}} will be skipped during data restore

Comment: [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:22:218 INFO  {db=OSystem} Storage data recover was completed [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:40:739 WARNI {db=dbCemMilM01} Storage 'dbCemMilM01' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:40:740 INFO  {db=dbCemMilM01} Looking for last checkpoint... [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:40:743 INFO  {db=dbCemMilM01} Found FUZZY checkpoint. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:40:746 INFO  {db=dbCemMilM01} Data restore procedure from FUZZY checkpoint is started. [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:27:40:750 WARNI {db=dbCemMilM01} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=2999, position=4107727}} will be skipped during data restore [OLocalPaginatedStorage]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:40:756 WARNI {db=dbCemMilM01} Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=2999, position=4107734}} com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null, previousCheckpoint=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=2999, position=4107687}} will be skipped during data restore [OLocalPaginatedStorage]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:40:762 WARNI {db=dbCemMilM01} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=2999, position=4107774}} will be skipped during data restore [OLocalPaginatedStorage]

Comment: 2016-08-02 08:27:40:765 INFO  {db=dbCemMilM01} Storage data recover was completed [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-02 08:29:19:768 INFO  {db=dbCemMilM01} [TIP] Query 'SELECT FROM Pesquisador' returned a result set with more than 10000 records. Check if you really need all these records, or reduce the resultset by using a LIMIT to improve both performance and used RAM [OProfilerStub]

Comment: I see "
SELECT FROM Pesquisador' returned a result set with more than 10000 records. Check if you really need all these records, or reduce the resultset by using a LIMIT to improve both performance and used RAM"

There is an issue on github about huge query results, the milestone is set to 3.0 version: github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2425

Comment: Hi @LuiNeumann Can you try to put an index?

Comment: Hi @Michela, I tried but the result as the same